# Query to select condition on same column with different values

Tags: sql

I have to select the `user_id` belongs to the `business_type_id` 1 & 2.

For example: following is my table:

```
user_id     business_type_id
101             1
101             1       
101             1
101             2
101             2
102             1
102             1
103             2       
103             2
103             2
```

Expected output:

> I want to find the `user_id` in both `business_type_id` `1 & 2`.

Result:

> 101 -> is the user_id present in both `business_type_id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the user_id with business_type_id = 1 OR business_type_id = 2

```
select distinct  user_id 
from  my_table  
where business_type_id in (1,2 )
```

if you want the user_id with  business_type_id = 1 AND business_type_id = 2

```
select  user_id 
from  my_table  
where business_type_id in (1,2 )
group by user_id  
having count(distinct business_type_id ) = 2
```

and    If you  want the user_id only in business_type_id = 1 AND business_type_id NOT =  2

```
select  user_id 
from  my_table  
where user_id  not  in  (
  select distinct user_id 
  from  my_table  
  where business_type_id = 2
) 
and  business_type_id  = 1
```

Comment: If i want the `user_id` only in `business_type_id` `1` and not in `2`

Comment: your 2nd answer is already given by @Yogesh almost 2minutes before of you

Answer (score 0):

You can do aggregation :

```
select user_id
from table t
where business_type_id in (1, 2)
group by user_id
having count(distinct business_type_id) = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT user_id FROM table_name WHERE business_type_id IN (1, 2) GROUP BY user_id`.